# How to setup SSL?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have been now researching since two days and can't find a clear answer.

1. I have purchased a Premium SSL certificate. Once I have
   created a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and send it to them to
   activate the SSL, is this carved in the stone for the entire year?
   What if I have a typo in CN (common name) etc? Would I be able to
   change it and resend the CSR again?
2. I can't find a clear answer what a fully-qualified domain name is.
   Most claim it should be example.com  but others claim it has to have
   a trailing dot -> example.com.  otherwise it could still be
   vulnerable to ma in between attacks.
3. During generation of CSR, I could also select if the SSL is used for
   Intel® vPro. I think this only makes sense if the SSL is used for
   secured remote desktop otherwise for plain e-commerce this option is
   pointless, is this correct?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You will need a new certificate if you want to change anything.
2. A [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) means a complete name: *host.domain.tld*
3. You are right.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, so a complete name could be also example.com as well as subdomain.example.com, correct?

Comment: That's correct Kave

Comment: I recently went thru getting my ssl for owa and after obtaining it i was able to import it via MS Exchange PowerShell

Comment: @Kave both *subdomain.example.com* and *example.com* names can be fully-qualified as long as the name **uniquely** identifies the host/server/device.